# Need Module for Images/Video in Node, works with Views

Tags: views, nodes, media, files

I'm using d7.2. I have been searching and working on this all day- can't figure it out. So I'm posting here for some help...

I have a Node that I want the users to be able to upload images and/or video to. They can upload either or BOTH if needs be. They can upload a single image, multiple images, single or multiple videos (3rd party hosted- you tube, vimeo, etc), or a combination of images and video.

I'd like for it to be displayed in a nice looking format- kind of like gallery formatter does (can't seem to get that to work for me)  with a larger image on top/middle, and thumbnails of the others on the side or bottom.  When the user clicks on the larger image, it'll open in lightbox.

I need it to work with views, as I'll be attaching a voting module to it, as well as others that will implement with Views.

I am really stuck and frustrated on this one. There doesn't seem to be any solid modules that can handle this- unless I'm just not seeing it.

I sincerely appreciate any/all help!

Answer (score 1):

For handling the video, check out the [Media module](http://drupal.org/project/media) or the [Video module](http://drupal.org/project/video).  These will allow you upload, manage, and reuse video files.

For images, these features have been put into Drupal core, so you shouldn't need an extra module for uploading, managing, and displaying images.

Once set up with that, you can theme the display of the fields and if you choose, add other modules (such as [Lightbox2](http://drupal.org/project/lightbox2)) to enhance the user's experience).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem comes in with the look/feel of this. If I want a medium size image (usually the first image uploaded, and will also be used for all thumbnails for the node)- and then smaller thumbnails underneath it. If you look at Gallery Formatter- that's the style I'm looking for. HOWEVER- how do you implement 3rd party hosted video with that at the same time?

Comment: @user Ah, you want to create a "gallery formatter look" with videos as well as images?  I don't know of any modules that will do that for videos but you could always create a custom module or find a javascript library that will assist with theming. You could use Gallery Formatter for images and then customize something for the videos as well

Comment: Gotcha- that's what I was afraid of. THanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

Try could try out this module: [Media Front](http://drupal.org/project/mediafront)

> The MediaFront module is a front end media solution for Drupal. It employs an innovative and intuitive administration interface that allows the website administrator to completely customize the front end media experience for their users without writing any code. In addition, this module provides an interface to which 3rd party media players can integrate and utilize settings presets to display rich media. Out-of-the-box, this module provides two media player solutions.